# WordApplication Document add text

Tags: delphi, com

How to paste some text to Word document if i have handle to TWordDocument or _Document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paste to the Range object of the document:

```
Document.Range(EmptyParam, EmptyParam).Paste;
```

or

```
Word.ActiveDocument.Range(EmptyParam, EmptyParam).Paste;
```

You can tell where to paste:

```
var
  R: OleVariant;
..
  R := 20;
  Document.Range(R, R).Paste;
```